# Syntax for multiple params in onclick remoteFunction in Grails

Tags: grails

I have code like this:

```
<button id="save" onclick = "${remoteFunction(controller: 'customer', 
                                                action: 'saveModifiedIndividualRecord',
                                    params: '\'yellowIssuesRemoved=\' + removedYellowIssues')}"> Save </button>
```

I would like to add some more params to the above code which are:

```
uniqueId: uniqueId, 
secondaryId: secondaryId,
redIssuesRemoved: removedRedIssues
```

but I can't quite get the syntax because I haven't done multiple params using the above technique before.

Edit: I think there is some kind of delimiter to separate multiple parameters using this technique but just can't seem to find an example of it. Or remember it.

Just tried a few variation of this with no luck:

```
<button id="save" onclick = "${remoteFunction(controller: 'customer', 
                                                action: 'saveModifiedIndividualRecord',
                                    params: '\'redIssuesRemoved=\' + removedRedIssues' +  '\'&yellowIssuesRemoved=\' + removedYellowIssues')}"> Save </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'` is mismatching with what you have tried now.

```
<button id="save" 
        onclick = "${remoteFunction(
          controller: 'customer', 
          action: 'saveModifiedIndividualRecord',
          params: '\'redIssuesRemoved=\' + removedRedIssues +  \'&yellowIssuesRemoved=\' + removedYellowIssues')}">
    Save 
</button>
```

Mark that there is no `'` after `removedRedIssues`. Watch how single quotes are escaped.

Also you can try using a map notation instead of request parameters for params. like

```
params: [redIssuesRemoved: removedRedIssues, yellowIssuesRemoved: removedYellowIssues]
```

Comment: Ok just confirmed that this is working with all my params now. Thanks.